Understanding inverse image functor in terms of the adjoint universal property
Vakil (in his Rising Sea Algebraic Geometry text) "defines" the inverse image functor as the adjoint of the pushforward functor. Then he asks you to solve certain problems below using this universal property. I can solve these problem concretely but not using the universal property. It's possible I don't know exactly what Vakil means when he refers to the universal property of an adjoint functor. I see wikipedia's definition of adjoint functors in terms of a universal property and this makes sense to me -- I see a triangle with a filler. But this is not Vakil's definition.
Adjoint functor notes
Vakil provides the standard definition in terms of a bijection between the relevant hom sets, which I won't reproduce here. See below, which I think is relevant.


Inverse Image definitions

Inverse image problems

Questions

So what is the specific universal property I'm working with to solve these problems? 1.5B and 1.5.1 don't seem helpful to me.
Perhaps partially work or give a hint for exercise 2.7C as a starting point.


Hint for 2.7C: Use (or show) that left adjoints preserve colimits.

Yes I used that approach to solve the proof. But it doesn't seem like I'm using any universal property of the adjoint to solve any of these problems.

In my view, the natural isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}(F(X),-)\cong \mathrm{Hom}(X,G(-))$ is the universal property of the left adjoint. Giving a universal property for an object $A$ in a category $\mathcal{C}$ amounts to specifying a functor $H\colon \mathcal{C}\to \mathsf{Set}$ and a natural isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}(A,-)\cong H(-)$ (or a contravariant functor $H$ to $\mathsf{Set}$ and a natural isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}(-,A)\cong H(-)$), i.e., giving an alternative way to specify a morphism $A\to B$ (or $B\to A$) by specifying an element of $H(B)$.
Now, whenever $A$ has a universal property, say $\mathrm{Hom}(A,-)\cong H(-)$, Yoneda gives us a "universal element" $u\in H(A)$ such that for any $x\in H(B)$, there exists a unique $f\colon A\to B$ such that $x = H(f)(u)$. This is the content of Exercise 1.5.B in the special case of the natural isomorphism $\mathrm{Hom}(F(X),-)\cong \mathrm{Hom}(X,G(-))$. But whenever an argument involves defining an arrow $A\to B$ by choosing an element of $H(B)$, I would describe this as "using the universal property", whether or not the argument mentions the universal element $u$.
For example, to solve Exercise 2.7.D, given the inclusion map $i\colon U\to X$, where $U\subseteq X$ is open, and a sheaf $\mathscr{G}$ on $X$, we want to define a morphism $\varphi\colon i^{-1}\mathscr{G}\to \mathscr{G}|_U$ (and show it's an isomorphism). By the universal property, to define this morphism, it suffices to define a map $\psi\colon\mathscr{G}\to i_*(\mathscr{G}|_U)$. That is, for all open $V$, we need to define $$\psi(V)\colon \mathscr{G}(V)\to i_*(\mathscr{G}|_U)(V) = \mathscr{G}|_U(i^{-1}(V)) = \mathscr{G}(V\cap U),$$ and we can take $\psi(V)$ to be the restriction map $\mathrm{res}_{V,V\cap U}$. Of course, now you need to check that $\psi$ is a morphism of sheaves and that the corresponding morphism $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.
For 2.7.C, we can solve the exercise without using the explicit description or the universal property (at least not directly). The key point is Remark 2.7.3, that taking stalks itself amounts to applying an inverse image functor.
Suppose $\pi\colon X\to Y$ is continuous and $\pi(p) = q$. Let $1$ be the singleton space, and let $c_p\colon 1\to X$ and $c_q\colon 1\to Y$ be the constant maps with value $p$ and $q$, respectively. Note that $\pi\circ c_p = c_q$. It follows that for any sheaf $\mathscr{G}$ on $Y$, $c_p^{-1}\pi^{-1}\mathscr{G} \cong c_q^{-1}\mathscr{G}$.
[Why? Well, one way to see this is that if $F$ is left adjoint to $G$ and $F'$ is left adjoint to $G'$, then $F\circ F'$ is left adjoint to $G'\circ G$. Now it is easy to check that $f\circ g = h$ implies $f_*\circ g_* = h_*$, and it follows by essential uniqueness of adjoints that $g^{-1}\circ f^{-1} \cong h^{-1}$.]
Now by Remark 2.7.3, $\mathscr{G}_q\cong c_q^{-1}\mathscr{G} \cong c_p^{-1}\pi^{-1}\mathscr{G} \cong (\pi^{-1}\mathscr{G})_p$, as desired.

I'm struggling to relate your definition of universal property with the "formal" one that I'm aware of here (wikipedia).

@IsaacR24 Well, I've never liked the account of universal properties that appears on Wikipedia. It seems unnecessarily obscure to me. Basically, the Wikipedia definition requires the universal property of $A\in C$ to be of the form $\mathrm{Hom}(A,-)\cong \mathrm{Hom}(X,F(-))$, where $F\colon C\to D$ is a functor and $X\in D$, i.e., taking $H(-)=\mathrm{Hom}(X,F(-))$, whereas I allow any functor $H\colon C\to \mathsf{Set}$.

Of course, for any functor $H$ to $\mathsf{Set}$, we have a natural isomorphism $H\cong \mathrm{Hom}(1,H(-))$, so every universal property in my sense can be put into the form required by the Wikipedia definition! (By taking $D=\mathsf{Set}$, $F=H$, and $X=1$, a singleton set.) Most modern category theory books define universal property in the way I did - see, for example, Riehl's Category Theory in Context.
